# Routes Consult with pgrouting / openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, pgrouting, postgis-2.0

I'm starting with pgrouting. After suffering a bit unable to put the data in osm postgis using osm2po with the excellent tutorial http://anitagraser.com/2011/12/15/an-osm2po-quickstart/ ran the sql generated by osm2po visualized data with http: / / localhost: 8888/Osm2poService routing is fantastic and has also insert the data in my town in postgis successfully.

Then I started reading the manual and pgrouting in http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.0/en/doc/index.html me questions arose:

1 - The data provided by osm2po are already topologically arranged just so I do consultations?

2 - The fields of my table are:

```
id
osm_id
osm_name
osm_meta
osm_source_id
osm_target_id
clazz
flags
source
target
km
kmh
cost
reverse_cost
x1
y1
x2
y2
geom_way
```

Can I get the total distance in miles doing a "sum" of the KM field, is this correct?

Where can I learn what each field, for example, do not know what the field clazz, cost, reverse_cost ....?

3 - The flow of my application the user is typing two addresses, I'll get the latitude and longitude of the point of origin and destination and select the launch in postgis, how do this if the source and target parameter settings are whole?

4- Does anyone have any examples of how to do this with openlayers?

---

Edited here

I'm getting the distance of the route like this:

```
SELECT 

         sum (cost) cost AS 
FROM pgr_dijkstra (
                 'SELECT id, source, target, the cost km FROM at_2po_4pgr' 
                 50347, 32988, false, false 
         );
```

Where 50347 and 32988 are my origin and destination. I do not understand what this format is, are coordinated? The coordinates of my geocode comes in decimal degrees are respectively 51.13, -29.77 and -51.21, -30.04 if I use them so do not run the sql.

Could you explain me I can pass the coordinates for the sql?

Comment: Please note that the Q&A format of this site requires us to stick to one question per thread. You're welcome to open multiple threads if you have more than one question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) Yes. osm2po creates a SQL import file, which already contains the routing topology.

(2) Yes. You just need to convert kilometers to miles. If you use `km AS cost` in your pgRouting query, then your route `cost` attribute will be in `km` as well.

(3) For the address lookup you need a Geocoder, for example [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim). When you know the point coordinates, you can route from/to the nearest source or target ID in your network.

(4) You may find the [pgRouting Workshop](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/) useful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply really helped me progress. 
But I still have a question about what format do I have to geocode the coordinates for the sql, I edited the question with details if you can thank me auxliar more.

Comment: You need a node ID for start and end point. If you have an address for example, then you first will geocode a latitude/longitude, and with this point you search for the nearest start/end node.